# I'm a newbie to python/Django and getting a value error and no http response error. Also when added with return statement, form is not updating

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, httpresponse

ValueError at /update_department/14
The view management.views.update_department didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.Also when added with return  statement data is not updating.

Request information
USER
admin

GET
No GET data

POST
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken
'XLqZBPhMKImvlfgWsNLeN1Ei8nz5u1HJ15IvAQV4JNwVMeG31rhDOD1q9PJuwXmz'
department_code
'15'
department_name_e
'Finance'
department_name_l
'Finance'
parent_code
''
submit
''

These are the details.I don't know why is there error here while all the posted data is right.also the form is not updating.

Models:

```
class Departments(models.Model):
    department_code = models.CharField(db_column='Department_Code', primary_key= True,  max_length=20, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')  # Field name made lowercase.
    department_name_e = models.CharField(db_column='Department_Name_E', max_length=50, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')  # Field name made lowercase.
    department_name_l = models.CharField(db_column='Department_Name_L', max_length=50, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')  # Field name made lowercase.
    parent_code = models.CharField(db_column='Parent_Code', max_length=20, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')  # Field name made lowercase.
    is_active = models.BooleanField(db_column='Is_Active')  # Field name made lowercase.
    created_by = models.IntegerField(db_column='Created_By')  # Field name made lowercase.
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_date')  # Field name made lowercase.
    modified_by = models.IntegerField(db_column='Modified_By')  # Field name made lowercase.
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Modified_date')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Departments'
        unique_together = (('department_code'),)
    def __str__(self):
        return str("self.department_name_e") or ''




View:


@login_required
def update_department(request, department_code):
    dep_up = Departments.objects.get(department_code=department_code)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DepartmentsForm(request.POST, instance = dep_up)
        if form.is_valid():
            department_code = form.cleaned_data['department_code']
            department_name_e = form.cleaned_data['department_name_e']
            department_name_l = form.cleaned_data['department_name_l']
            parent_code = form.cleaned_data['parent_code']
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.is_active = True
            obj.created_by = request.user.id
            obj.created_date = datetime.today()
            obj.modified_by = request.user.id
            obj.modified_date = datetime.today()
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('department_list')



forms:



class DepartmentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Departments
        fields = ['department_code','department_name_e','department_name_l','parent_code']



HTML:





{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Update Company{% endblock title  %}

{% block body %}
<div style="margin-left:22%" class=" top-marg">
  <h2 ><strong>Company:</strong></h2><br><br>

  <form class="" action="{%url 'update_company' comp_up.company_code  %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%" class="form-floating   ">
  <input type="text" value="{{comp_up.company_code}}" class="form-control" id="company_code"  name="company_code" placeholder="Company Code" required>
  <label style="margin-left:15px" for="company_code">Company Code</label>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%" class="form-floating ">
  <input type="text" value="{{comp_up.company_name_e}}" class="form-control" id = "company_name_e" name="company_name_e" placeholder="Enter Company" required>
  <label style="margin-left:15px" for="company_name_e">Company Name English</label>
  </div>
<br>

  <div style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%" class="form-floating ">
  <input type="text" value="{{comp_up.company_name_l}}" class="form-control" id = "company_name_l" name="company_name_l" placeholder="Enter Company" required>
  <label style="margin-left:15px" for="company_name_e">Company Name Local</label>
  </div>
<br>

  <div style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%" class="form-floating ">
    <input type="tel" value="{{comp_up.tel}}" class="form-control" id = "tel" name="tel" placeholder="Telephone Number" required>
    <label style="margin-left:15px" for="tel">Telephone Number</label>
  </div>
<br>

  <div style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%" class="form-floating ">
  <input type="tel" value="{{comp_up.fax}}" class="form-control" id = "fax" name="fax" placeholder="Enter Fax"required>
  <label style="margin-left:15px" for="fax"> Fax Number</label>
  </div>
<br>

  <div style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%" class="form-floating ">
    <textarea name="address"  class="form-control" rows="4" cols="100" placeholder="Address" required>{{comp_up.address}}</textarea>
    <label style="margin-left:15px" for="address">Address</label>
  </div>
<br>

  <div style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%" class="form-floating ">

    <select class="form-control" name="country_id" required>

      <option value="{{comp_up.country_id.id}}" >{{comp_up.country_id.country_name_e}}</option>
      {% for con in country %}
      <option value="{{con.id}}" >{{con.country_name_e}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>

  </div>
  <br>

    <label style = "margin-left:21%; " for="logo">Logo</label>
  <div class="form-floating" >
  <input value="{{comp_up.}}" style = "margin-left:21%;" accept="image/*" type="file" name="logo" onchange="loadFile(event)"  required> <br>
  <img style = "margin-left:21%;" id="output" >
  <script>
    var loadFile = function(event) {
      var output = document.getElementById('output');
      output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      output.onload = function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(output.src) // free memory
      }
    };
  </script>

  </div>
<br><br>

  <center>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Update</button>&nbsp;
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href = '{%url 'company_list'%}'" name="cancel">Cancel</button>

  </center>

  
</form>


</div>

{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: The solution tells to add return, i have already used return.

Comment: There are _multiple_ answers on that question, please read the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided HttpReponse only for POST and valid form. You should give the standard response (with empty form) for fresh entries or posting with errors. Like this:

```
@login_required
def update_department(request, department_code):
    dep_up = Departments.objects.get(department_code=department_code)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DepartmentsForm(request.POST, instance = dep_up)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('department_list')
    form = DepartmentsForm()
    return render(request, 'template.html', context={'form': form})
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /update_department/12